# How to filter date column using dataTable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, datatables

I am new to this dataTable concept,I am using this same code in my file kindly check once this link https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html, in this I have three files like server.php ,ssp.class.php and page.php (in server.php file database related code is there and in ssp.class.php I have filter related data then page.php I have front end code ).
In server.php file my code like this :

```
$filename = 'filterdate.php';
$columns = array(
    array( 'db' => 'filename', 'dt' => 0 ),
    array( 'db' => 'date', 'dt' => 1 ),
    array( 'db' => 'time',  'dt' => 2 ),
    array( 'db' => 'source',   'dt' => 3 ),
    array( 'db' => 'destination',     'dt' => 4 ),
    array( 'db' => 'duration',   'dt' => 5 ),
    array( 'db' => 'filename',     'dt' => 6 )
);
```

Here my query is I what filter the date column from two input fields called start_date and end_date with datepicker.

i was trying this code:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {      
  var oTable = $('#example').DataTable({
    "oLanguage": {
      "sSearch": "Filter Data"
    },
    "iDisplayLength": -1,
    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
   });  
  $("#datepicker_from").datepicker({
      dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
    showOn: "button",
    buttonImage: "assets/images/cal.gif",
    buttonImageOnly: false,
    "onSelect": function(date) {
      minDateFilter = new Date(date).getTime();
      oTable.draw();
    }
  }).keyup(function() {
    minDateFilter = new Date(this.value).getTime();
    oTable.draw();
    //alert(minDateFilter);
  });

  $("#datepicker_to").datepicker({
      dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
    showOn: "button",
    buttonImage: "assets/images/cal.gif",
    buttonImageOnly: false,
    "onSelect": function(date) {
      maxDateFilter = new Date(date).getTime();
      oTable.draw();
    }
  }).keyup(function() {
    maxDateFilter = new Date(this.value).getTime();
    oTable.draw();
    //alert(maxDateFilter);
  });

//});
    } );

// Date range filter
minDateFilter = "";
maxDateFilter = "";  
$.fn.dataTableExt.afnFiltering.push(
 function(oSettings, aData, iDataIndex) {
    alert("inside table");
    if (typeof aData._date == 'undefined') {
      aData._date = new Date(aData[1]).getTime();

    }

    if (minDateFilter && !isNaN(minDateFilter)) {
      if (aData._date < minDateFilter) {
        return false;
      }
    }

    if (maxDateFilter && !isNaN(maxDateFilter)) {
      if (aData._date > maxDateFilter) {
        return false;
      }
    }

    return true;
  }
  );
```

In this code I am not getting filter and maxDateFilter and minDateFilter giving alert but in `$.fn.dataTableExt.afnFiltering.push( function(oSettings, aData, iDataIndex) {` funtion I am not getting alert box.

Comment: any error in consol log?

Comment: Are you using individual column filtering like present in url: https://datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter.html . if yes then individual value gets sent to server side. If you want to send any extra parameters then have a look at the https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/custom_vars.html

Comment: You can do it easyly with a plugin see discussion here https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/39894/date-range-filter and here live example with js http://live.datatables.net/zuciyawi/1/edit

Comment: Thanks @SimoneRossaini one error is comimg like ```Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.' ``` I think this is datepicker css ```<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"></script>```

Comment: Thanks @PrasadWargad https://datatables.net/examples/plug-ins/range_filtering.html like this I need ,instead of age I want filter date column ,kindly check once that like.

Comment: Thanks @Dilek i have tried that live example with js ,that code working when i take only test.php file but it comes to my file called page.php it is not working ,i am not understanding why it is working in test.php file and why not in my page.php file .my page.php file taken from this https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html .about this i have explained above .

Comment: @MuralaSandeep did you include https://momentjs.com/ js file into your page ?

Comment: @Dilek Thanks for your response .I did not include momentjs.com ,sorry i don't  know that conecpt also ,I am new to this concept called dataTable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/14rbugwn/

Date filters added against a JAVASCRIPT based datatables. Have used HTML5 input type date elements for datepicker. While filtering the data, have converted the input dates to unix timestamp and then matched the data present in the table.

JS Code:

```
function toTimestamp(inputDateTime) {
    if( inputDateTime == null || typeof inputDateTime == 'undefined' ) {
        inputDateTime = new Date();
    }
    return Math.round(new Date(inputDateTime).getTime()/1000);
}

$.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
    function( settings, data, dataIndex ) {
        var min = parseInt( $('#min').val(), 10 );
        var max = parseInt( $('#max').val(), 10 );
        var age = parseFloat( data[3] ) || 0; // use data for the age column

        var from_date = toTimestamp($('#from_date').val());
        var to_date = toTimestamp($('#to_date').val());
        var start_date = toTimestamp(data[4]);

        var record_found = false;

        if ( ( isNaN( min ) && isNaN( max ) ) ||
             ( isNaN( min ) && age <= max ) ||
             ( min <= age   && isNaN( max ) ) ||
             ( min <= age   && age <= max ) )
        {
            record_found = true;
        }

        if( record_found && 
            ( ( isNaN( from_date ) && isNaN( to_date ) ) || 
              ( isNaN( from_date ) && from_date <= to_date ) || 
              ( from_date <= start_date && isNaN( to_date ) ) || 
              ( from_date <= start_date && start_date <= to_date ) ) )
        {
            record_found = true;
        }
        else
        {
            record_found = false;
        }
        return record_found;
    }
);

$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#example').DataTable();

    // Event listener to the two range filtering inputs to redraw on input
    $('#min, #max').keyup( function() {
        table.draw();
    } );

    // Event listener to the two date filtering inputs to redraw on input
    $('#from_date, #to_date').keyup( function() {
        table.draw();
    } );
} );
```

For having solution in combination with Server Side Datatable, you can enable individual input filters against the datatable like the way shown in an url: https://datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter.html . Input filters user entered data gets posted to server side, you can view the posted data using print_r($_POST); for more details.